# how to compare my app battery usage to other apps usage?

Tags: automated-testing, java, android, ios

I have built a navigation app (android and iOS)

I want to automatically\manually test its battery consumption while navigating from A to B.

And compare it to the battery consumption of external apps like Google maps.

How would you advise me to do so?

For external application I usually use `appiu` for ui automating. But it requires connecting to a computer with a USB which charge the battery as I test.

For `android` I know I can use `robotium` and disconnect the smartphone from data-charging USB. But then how can i test the battery consumption?

For `iOS` - what is the equivalent to `robotium` or in general, how would you test it?

Comment: What about battery usage info under 'android settings section. Are those details not accurate or are you looking for something else (more detailed)?

Comment: That's an option. I would prefer tools that allows automation. What would you suggest for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your battery status for iOS: Go to Settings → General → Usage Usage. Under the section at the top labeled   Battery, tap Battery Usage. Check usage and stand by status in that you can view last charger time and remaining percentage. 
   iPhone 5s battery life 10h 57m 24s.
2. Check your battery status for Android:
   The apps home screen gives an adequate quick-glance overview of battery usage according to category: phone calls, screen time, WiFi activity, etc. With the App Sucker, however, you can get a more detailed breakdown of CPU usage, including all details.